# Real world implementation of interfaces

Tags: php, oop, interface

This question might sound obvious and might be stupid as well. But I am trying to figure out why do I need to use interfaces? I think I can handle most of the things which interfaces do using classes then what's the point of using them? It's true that I might end up in problems if I don't interfaces but I am trying to figure out what problems are caused by not using interfaces?

One use of interfaces is that they allow us to define behaviors and put restrictions on of classes which implement them.

Another use is that interface work as types and I can use interfaces for type hinting as shown below.

```
//Java example
public interface IPaintable{
   void Paint(System.Drawing.Color color);
}

public void Paint(IPaintable item, System.Drawing.Color color){
   item.Paint(color);
}
```

But are there any other use of interfaces in PHP?

I.e. What advantages do I get by using interfaces in the code below.

```
//Non interface implementation
    <?php
    class DBPersonProvider
    {
        public function getPerson($givenName, $familyName)
        {
            /* go to the database, get the person... */
            $person = new Person();
            $person->setPrefix("Mr.");
            $person->setGivenName("John");
            return $person;
        }
    }

    /* I need to get person data... */
    $provider = new DBPersonProvider();
    $person = $provider->getPerson("John", "Doe");

    echo($person->getPrefix());
    echo($person->getGivenName());

    ?>

    //Implementation with interface

        <?php
        interface PersonProvider
        {
            public function getPerson($givenName, $familyName);
        }

        class DBPersonProvider implements PersonProvider 
        {
            public function getPerson($givenName, $familyName)
            {
            /* pretend to go to the database, get the person... */
            $person = new Person();
            $person->setPrefix("Mr.");
            $person->setGivenName("John");
            return $person;
        }
    }


    /* I need to get person data... */
   $provider = new DBPersonProvider();
    $person = $provider->getPerson("John", "Doe");

    echo($person->getPrefix());
    echo($person->getGivenName());
    ?>
```

Comment: You define a **protocol** using an interface. What you get is the basis of reliability. Imagine a `Person`. Every person has a body which has organs. Therefore your interface would implement the organs. Every person is different. John, Jack, Michael, Christina etc are all different, but are made out of functionally same components. Therefore, when you create a new person, you **have** to have their core parts created which interoperate and make the body work. That's why interfaces are there - they enforce a protocol on any implementing class.

Comment: Agree. I have pointed this out in my question "One use of interfaces is that they allow us to define behaviors and put restrictions on of classes which implement them."

Comment: That's all you get. There is no other benefit to using interfaces. If you have a small project, you probably won't benefit that much. However if there's 50 of you working on a project and you're the core developer of a feature - it's a smart move to use an interface which is implemented by abstract class which is then extended by classes other devs do. And you just enforced a protocol. It's an architectural and organisational thing mostly.

Comment: @N.B. I completely agree with you. But I have seen lot of small applications using interfaces. The problem with interfaces is that when your coding you have to maintain lot of files and every time you add new methods you have to and change your interfaces. Interfaces are fine if we are working in a team like you said but I am looking for advantages that interface offer in small applications and small development teams.

Comment: Even small applications get big. Also, if you have to change the interface after you change the class, that just means your feature is far from fully explored (nothing bad with that). Once you do your R&D, that's the time when you can safely say "I know everything about this feature, I broke it down to N components and this will be the interface they have to implement in order to achieve interoperability". If there's even only 2 of you - trust me, treat the code as if there were 5000 people working on it. You have no idea what kind of massacre 1 extra dev. can do to the codebase..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I write a nice library that interacts with the database.** And I use `MySQL`. When you purchase my library, you know it's `MySQL` based but you roll with `SQL Server`. **I was considerate enough to create interfaces for the Database access.** And I provided an implementation for `MySQL`. Now you can implement your own `SQL Server` wrapper around my database access interface, and then use it as a `__construct()` argument for the classes in the library you will use to change move storage to `SQL Server`.

**Interfaces are very useful for library / reusable code writers *like me* :)** They are code contracts that have to be obeyed. **You know that any class that implements them WILL have a set of functions exactly as the Interface declared them.** And you can also statically type them in function arguments like `function(MyInterface $Object)` which enforces, at PHP compiler level, that `$Object` must be implementing `MyInterface`.

**PS**: *Abstract classes are good enough for the rest of self-written code consuming developers...*

**UPDATE**:

```
/**
* Database Access functionality blueprint.
*/
interface IDatabaseAccess {
    public function Connect();
    public function Query();
    public function Fetch();
}

/**
* Database Access functionality implementation for MySQL.
*/
class MySqlDatabaseAccess implements IDatabaseAccess {
    public function Query(){
        // do mysql stuff
    }
    public function Fetch(){
        // do mysql stuff
    }
}

/**
* Database Access functionality implementation for SQLServer.
*/
class SqlServerDatabaseAccess implements IDatabaseAccess {
    public function Query(){
        // do sqlserver stuff
    }
    public function Fetch(){
        // do sqlserver stuff
    }
}

/**
* Database Access consumer that's database system agnostic.
*/
class DatabaseAccessConsumer {
    protected $_Provider = null;
    public function __construct(IDatabaseAccess $Provider){
        $this->_Provider = $Provider;
        $this->_Provider->Connect();
    }
    public function Query(){
        return $this->_Provider->Query();
    }
    public function Fetch(){
        return $this->_Provider->Fetch();
    }
}
```

^ *code that should speak for itself*.

Comment: Agree. I have all ready pointed this out in my question. "One use of interfaces is that they allow us to define behaviors and put restrictions on of classes which implement them."

Comment: @JayBhatt So what else do you need?

Comment: If I am building a commercial product I would definitely use interfaces as they would provide good direction for future developments.  I am writing a simple application and in this context what advantages will the interfaces offer?

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces actually provide less features than abstract classes (you cannot implement anything).

But they resolve the problem of multiple inheritance. Most modern language do not allow a class to derive more than one class. By using an interface, which does not implement any method, you are sure there is no ambiguity when you invoke a method from the interface (because there is no implementation).

Example (syntactically not valid):

```
class A {
    public foo() {
        echo 'I am A and I foo';
    };
    public 
}

class B {
    public foo() {
        echo 'I am B and I foo';
    }
}

class C extends A, B { // invalid
    public bar() {
        foo(); // which one? A's or B's?
    }
}
```

Second example:

```
class A {
    public foo() {
        echo 'I am A and I foo';
    };
}

interface iB {
    public foo();
    public bar();
}

interface iC {
    public foo();
    public qux();
}

class D extends A implements iB, iC {

    public bar() {
         foo(); // no ambiguity, this is A::foo(), even if the method is also declared in the interfaces
    }

    public qux() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are just blueprints of classes - they are ways of saying "If you are going to be doing something with this type of class, it must have this and do this." It allows you to control - to an extent - what another class will have/do at a minimum for a given situation. Not every situation calls for an iterface. Interfaces are best used in situations when you need to have some control over the basic code of certain classes but you may not be the one writing them. If you know that the extended classes will have x properties and y methods, then you can do basic future class support.